# Validate that a PowerShell parameter is alphanumeric

Tags: powershell

I simply want to validate that a parameter is only made up of alphanumeric characters. I've tried this, but it doesn't behave as I'd like:

```
param(
    [ValidatePattern('[a-zA-Z0-9]')]$someVariableThatShouldOnlyContainAlphaNumerics = 'something_with_underscores'
)
write-host $someVariableThatShouldOnlyContainAlphaNumerics
```

Returns:

> something_with_underscores

I'm clearly missing something obvious. Any suggestions?

Comment: `[ValidatePattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$')]`? You need to validate the whole string. I am in the middle of testing but I think you need that. Setting a default will override this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ValidatePattern` supports regex. If the pattern matches the string is validated. You are not validating all characters in the string... just *one*!

Changing the regex pattern to match the entire string would be one approach. Other regex will also suffice.

```
[ValidatePattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$')]$someVariableThatShouldOnlyContainAlphaNumerics = 'something_with_underscores'
```

Note that setting a default will *bypass* this validation as it is not being passed to the function.

Comment: fantastic, thank you @matt. Also didn't realise that the default overrode any parameter validation. Learn something new every day. thanks.